# Why does listView addHeaderView() display nothing?

Tags: android, listview

Why listView can't addHeaderView to itself?

I have added the params into the header rather than WRAP_CONTENT,MATCH_PARETN.

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView list  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        LinearLayout head = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                200,200
        );
        head.setLayoutParams(params);
        list.addHeaderView(head);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What should i do?

Comment: Do you set adapter to listview anywhere

Comment: without setting adapter to listview you can't able to view it as well as before setting adapter to listview need to set header to listview then only you got header in listview

Answer (score 0):

Try to imprort LayoutParams from RelativeLayout class instead of AbsListView. I think it may be problem of Class casting.